# Permutation Problem - Seating with Empty Chairs

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are 3 men and 3 women to be seated in a row of 10 chairs. In how many diﬀerent ways can they be seated if one man must be seated at each end of the row?

I began by calculating $_3P_2 = 6$ for the possible combinations for the end seats. The book gives the answer as 10,080, which I obtained by multiplying the first result by $_8P_4 = 1680$. I am unsure, however, about this second part of the problem, and I really only got there after trial-and-error, so I don't really understand why it works.

My understanding of the permutation formula $_nP_k$ is that it is for selecting $k$ objects from $n$ objects when order matters. So, if I were selecting $4$ people to fill $4$ remaining seats, it would make sense to me, but I don't understand where the $4$ empty seats come into play. Shouldn't there be many more possible permutations when accounting for the different positions of the empty chairs?

Comment: As an aside, $~_4P_4=4!=4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1 = 24\neq 1680 = ~_8P_4=8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5$

Comment: Woops! Meant $_8P_4$

Comment: So, you have the 8 remaining seats, and you want to pick four of them in a specific order.  Into those seats we place the four remaining people (*where the people are ordered arbitrarily, e.g. by age, to avoid overcounting*).  The seats not used in this process remain empty.

Comment: @JMoravitz But isn't this the same thing you would do if you had 4 remaining seats and wanted to fill them with 4 people in a specific order? Shouldn't the two problems be different? e.g. 1234 is different from 1_2_3_4_____.

Comment: It is not immediately clear to me where the disconnect is occurring in your understanding.  You understood my explanation below I assume, yes?  If we had only six chairs total, when we chose where the final man sits we would have only four options instead of eight options.  When we chose where the youngest woman sat, we would have three remaining options instead of seven remaining, etc...  In using $~_8P_4$ here, we are looking at our eight remaining chairs, and deciding how to place the four namecards on the chairs designating where our four remaining people sit and describing this as 1 step.

Comment: Ah, I see my mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignore "permutation" formulas and just do this directly via rule of product.  (*It is afterall from the rule of product that we get the permutation formulas in the first place*).

- Choose which man sits at the far left end (*three options*)
- Choose which man sits at the far right end (*two remaining options*)
- Choose which seat from those left available the remaining man sits (*eight remaining options*)
- Choose which seat from those left available the youngest woman sits (*seven remaining options*)
- Choose which seat from those left available the youngest remaining woman sits (*six remaining options*)
- Choose which seat from those left available the youngest remaining woman sits (*five remaining options*)

Multiplying the number of options for each step together yields the total:

$3\cdot 2\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5 = 10080$

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! Is this how you would do it, or is there another method I should be considering?

Comment: @T.Biscuit As you get more familiar with common problems, you can identify answers to subproblems much more quickly, for example being able to replace $8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5$ as a four-step rule of product explanation with $~_8P_4$ using a "permutation" explanation.  Similarly, you can recognize when binomial coefficients or stirling numbers of first or second kind, or several other common numbers can be used without taking the time to rederive them on the spot.  Especially as final answers become more complicated and convoluted, being able to spot such shortcuts can make it easier to read.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First you choose $2$ man out of $3$ which are sited at the each end and multiply by $2$. Now from the other $8$ chairs you choose $4$ chair and then arrange the rest $4$ people on this chairs (take all permutation of these $4$). So the answer is: $${3\choose 2}\cdot 2\cdot {8\choose 4}\cdot 4! = 10080$$